# Changing Ubuntu 11.04 default terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I upgraded a Ubuntu system from 10 to 11.04 (natty narwhal) a couple of days ago. A few things to tweak but generally all good and the Unity interface is..well..different.

I'm now accessing the system remotely from my OS X laptop using ssh and seeing some very weird behaviour. Starting one terminal window and ssh'ing works as expected.

Starting a second terminal window and ssh'ing in produces *exactly the same output*.

*Pressing return in one window produces the same effect in both windows.*

I am somewhat mystified as I've never seen this behaviour before. Nothing has changed on the OS X terminal config since the upgrade so I'm guessing this is some issue with using a different default terminal emulator in Ubuntu..

Answer (score 4):

Well, I eventually tracked it down.

The 11.04 upgrade added:

. $(which byobu-launch)

at the end of my .profile.

This was obviously to give me some fancy status info at the bottom of my terminal. Unfortunately it had the weird duplication effect and removing it has solved the issue.

Comment: A quick Google search reveals that Byobu is a fancier version of `screen`, which explains why you were seeing the "duplication" -- you were in fact using *exactly* the same terminal session. Odd that Ubuntu would have made such (nonstandard) behavior the default...